# Magento 1.9.1.0 - Upload PDF File Type in Wysiwyg Editor and show PDF Icon

Tags: magento-1.9, cms, css, pdf, wysiwyg

I made a custom module allowing user to upload `.PDF` file type in `CMS > Pages`. The code used is below:

**app/etc/modules**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Pdf_WysiwygFiles>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Pdf_WysiwygFiles>
  </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Pdf/WysiwygFiles/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Pdf_WysiwygFiles>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Pdf_WysiwygFiles>
  </modules>
  <adminhtml>
    <cms>
      <browser>
        <extensions>
          <allowed>
            <jpg>1</jpg>
            <jpeg>1</jpeg>
            <png>1</png>
            <gif>1</gif>
            <pdf>1</pdf>
          </allowed>
        </extensions>
      </browser>
    </cms>
  </adminhtml>
</config>
```

This works in `CE-1.9` and does allow to upload PDF file when you click on **Insert Image** button and does not allow to `link` it.

Also, how to add a `pdf preview icon` for each file uploaded ? The result would be like below image

[image]

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: @RKT-JoinMageStackDay2015, the above code says what I tried.

Answer (score 8):

In order to allow to upload and link pdf file, I modified your **config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Pdf_WysiwygFiles>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Pdf_WysiwygFiles>
  </modules>
  <adminhtml>
    <cms>
      <browser>
        <extensions>
          <allowed>
            <pdf>1</pdf>
          </allowed>
        </extensions>
      </browser>
    </cms>
  </adminhtml>
</config>
```

For the icon you can use css styles. Add this in your stylesheet, for example:
**skin/frontend/rwd/default/css/styles.css**

```
.col-main a[href$=".pdf"]:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: url(../images/icon_pdf.png) no-repeat;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

EDIT:

Removed this part:

```
          <media_allowed>
            <pdf>1</pdf>
          </media_allowed>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but with my `config.xml` I can still insert `link`, upload pdf file and insert it. What is the base difference between `<media_allowed>` and `<allowed>`

Comment: And how do I know if the file type uploaded is a `.doc/.xls/.pdf` ?

Comment: I think @Vikram is right, "media_allowed" isn't present anywhere in Magento so probably has no effect.  Maybe it used to in old versions but I checked down to 1.4.0.0 and couldn't find anything.

Comment: It looks like you are right, it has no effect.

Comment: This is not enough any more, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/44387645/719023

Answer (score 1):

For upload pdf file on WYSIWYG follow the below steps:

We need to upload pdf files through the WYSIWYG tool on Magento. I have
checked the native functionality and it allows by default only images (jpg,
png and gif).

So, to change the initial behavior I opened the file
app/code/core/Mage/Cms/etc/config.xml, which defines the filetypes that can
be uploaded, and around line 110 I have added the line 1 as
below:

```
<allowed>
<jpg>1</jpg>
<jpeg>1</jpeg>
<png>1</png>
<gif>1</gif>
  <pdf>1</pdf>
</allowed>
```

Now refresh the browser and you can upload pfd file also.

Comment: So you are practically editing a Core file, right? Which is always a bad idea. The very moment an upgrade or patch will update this file, your own updates are lost.

Answer (score 0):

in Order to allow upload a pdf you should add the following in a modoules config.xml

```
<adminhtml>
        <cms>
            <browser>
                <extensions>
                    <image_allowed>
                        <pdf>1</pdf>
                    </image_allowed>
                </extensions>
            </browser>
        </cms>
    </adminhtml>
```